# ASP.NET insert partial view jQuery using @Ajax.JavascriptEncode & insertBefore(): double quotes generated

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I update my last question in a more (I hope) clear way.

Does someone know why this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#inner').click(function () {
        $('<div class="dropHere">@Ajax.JavaScriptStringEncode(Html.Partial("EditorAddInvoiceDetailsPartial").ToHtmlString()) </div>').insertBefore('#inner');

    });

});
```

generates my partial view with double quotes everywhere they were simple initialy (in the partialview.cshtml). The insertion made look like this:

```
<fieldset id="productDetails">
    <legend>Details</legend>
    <div class="dropHere">
        <div class=""editor-label""> Product: </div>
        <div class=""editor-field"">
            <select id=""ProductId"" class=""ProductId"" name=""ProductId"">
                <option value=""""></option>
                <option value=""1"">Samsung</option>
                <option value=""2"">Seagate</option>
                <option value=""3"">OCZ</option>
                <option value=""4"">Asus</option>
                <option value=""5"">HP</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class=""editor-label""> Price: </div>
        <div class=""editor-field"">
        <div class=""editor-label""> Tax: </div>
        <div class=""editor-field"">
        <div class=""editor-label""> Quantity: </div>
        <div class=""editor-field"">
        <div class=""editor-label""> Subtotal Excl.VAT: </div>
        <div class=""editor-field"">
        <div class=""editor-label""> Subtotal VAT: </div>
        <div class=""editor-field"">
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

I tried to find some solution, but nothing relevant. It is possible to fix that or it is better to find a new way to insert my partial view here.

Comment: I've an answer but the div.changeProductPrice is exists when laoding the page the first time or is it added when clicking on the inner event.

Comment: it exist when loading the page with data-index="1", then when you click on button add new product, it's created and putted before the button with data-index="2"

Comment: But when you enter the first time does it exists?

Comment: I really think that the main issue here is to escape double quotes generated by innerBefore function. With @Ajax.JavascriptStringEncode, there is a need to escape properly double quotes, etc. In this case, because of Html.DropdownList attributes I can't escape them because then Html.DropdownList do not have what she/he wants and it do not work. I think that's the first thing to figure out...

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i would do it, first i'll put both events inside the same `.ready()` function. Also i guess there's a div outside the .changeProductPrice, let's called it .wrapper, the problem on your example might be, that you add the event for the initial .changeProductPrice, then when you add a new one it overrides it and gets lots, in my example i add the live evento the parent so when a new one it's added it won't get lost, but it attached to their childrens (changeProductPrice). Do i explain myself?

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var index = 2;

    $('#inner').on('click', function () {


        $('<div data-index="' + index + '" class="changeProductPrice"><div class="editor-label"> Product: </div> <div class="editor-field">@Ajax.JavaScriptStringEncode(Html.DropDownList("ProductId",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ProductId, "",  new { @class = "ProductId"}).ToHtmlString())</div><div class="editor-label">Price:</div><div class="editor-field"><input class="productprice" value="" /></div></div><div class="editor-label">Tax:</div><div class="editor-field">@Ajax.JavaScriptStringEncode(@Html.DropDownList("TaxId", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.TaxId, "", new { @class = "producttax" }).ToHtmlString())</div><div class="editor-label">Quantity:</div><div class="editor-field"><input class="productquantity" name="Qtn" value="" /></div>').insertBefore("#inner");
        index++;
    });

    $('.wrapper').on('change', '.changeProductPrice', function () {
        var url = '@Url.Action("SortPrices", "Invoice", null)';
        var ProductId = $(this).val();
        var el = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            data: { id: ProductId },
            success: function (result) {

                 el.parent().parent().find('.productprice').val(result);
                 el.parent().parent().find('.productprice').change();

                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Btw, i'm using .on() functions because the're new and does the same thing as click, live, etc.

Comment: Looks good, I think I understand more or less your point, will test it now. Thank you!

Comment: I tried it but still it do not work, and now even not for the first one. And the "" problem is still actual. To explain my self here what firebug shows after adding new product(inner) -> <div class="changeProductPrice" data-index="2">
<div class="editor-label"> Product: </div>
<div class="editor-field">
<select id=""ProductId"" class=""ProductId" valid" name=""ProductId"">
<option value=""""></option>
<option value=""1"">Samsung</option>
<option value=""2"">Seagate</option>
<option value=""3"">OCZ</option>
<option value=""4"">Asus</option>
<option value=""5"">HP</option>
</select>
</div>..

Comment: If you install the addon Firequery for firebug, you can check if the event has been asigned to the element.

Comment: Skatox, thanks for your help, the event is not assigned because js do no recognize my class names with the double quotes. I am sreaching for another way to insert the part with invoice details to my view dynamicly right now, to avoid the insertion which generates supplementary double quotes. Still I am curious, why it does it like this. Anyhow, thank you for tips.

Comment: I'm glad you have advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than build the partial via that string, why not just use Ajax to render the partial via a controller action.

```
$('#drophere').load('/Editor/InvoiceDetails');
```

That way you can build a model server side for the partial view easily as well if necessary.

Comment: It's what I finaly did, like this: $(document).ready(function () {


    $('#inner').click(function () {
         
        $('<fieldset class="dropHere"><legend>Details</legend></fieldset>').insertBefore('#inner');
        $.ajax({          url: '/Invoice/EditorAddInvoiceDetailsPartial/', 
             success: function (data) {  
                      $('.dropHere').html(data);
      
             }
         });
 
     });
 });

Comment: Now, my problem is to find out, how do I save that part of partial view data in the db with the submit button of the general fieldset where it is insetrted, with the possibility of having many partial (many products details added to one invoice).. :=)

Comment: The problem with loading the partial view like this, is that when I fill the inputs and click again on Add products button, it inserts the second partial view but erase all data's in the previous one (guess I have to work it out in my controller)

Comment: If you need to be able to add many copies of this partial view use jquery get and one of the jquery append methods instead of load.

Comment: To save that part of the partial view put the controls into a form element and a dd a submit button. You can specify what controller action to post to in the form element. You can also the bind to a save model that has all of your validation attributes on it, required etc.